# 'type' word can not be appended as query strings on branch.io deeplink

Tags: android, branch.io

I've tried to append query strings on branch.io deeplink to pass data from link to app.

The test is like this :

*https://example.app.link?type=123&hello=world*

but in Android, 'type' parameter is dropped not like 'hello'

Here is the dump of Intent :

> [branch_data={"~id":"0","+url":"https://example.app.link/?hello=123","hello":"123","~creation_source":6,"+domain":"example.app.link","+click_timestamp":1511169927,"+clicked_branch_link":true,"+match_guaranteed":true,"+is_first_session":true}]

I assume 'type' word is reserved, are there another keywords like this?

And is there any way to use 'type' word as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amruta from [Branch.io](https://branch.io/) here:

As you guessed, the `type` keyword is reserved and hence cannot be used as a custom query parameter. Unfortunately, there is no way around this.

Here is a list of reserved keywords

`` 'iframe_src', 'has_app', 'app_id', 'data', 'tags', '~tags', 'channel', '~channel', 'feature', '~feature', 'stage', '~stage', 'campaign', '`~campaign', 'type', 'duration', 'click', 'callback', 'post_data', 'branch_key', '$journeys_title', '$journeys_description', '$journeys_icon_image_url', '$journeys_reviews' ``